# How To Include Header Files In C

Tags: c, gcc, command-line, compiler-errors, c-header

I don't know how to include my own header files in my source file.

I declare addition in my header file(myhead.h):

```
int addition(int a, int b);
```

In the source file I define it(myhead.c):

```
int addition(int a, int b){
     return a+b;
}
```

In the third source file I include the header file and use addition(processSimulator.c):

```
#include "myhead.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
     printf("Compiled %d\n", addition(3,5));
}
```

[It gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLIjo.jpg)

Comment: This is linker error and not about headers. You need to compile both C files and link them. (just pass both to your gcc command).

Comment: cannot see the image, are you compiling like this `gcc processSimulator.c myhead.c` ?

Comment: No I wasn't and that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add myhead.c file to gcc arguments `gcc processSimulator.c my head.c`